# C++ OpenGL Rendering Simple OBJ From File

Tags: c++, opengl, render

I am currently following a basic OpenGL tutorial where the goal is to read data from an .OBJ file and then render the model. The tutorial is located here - http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-7-model-loading/.

Currently, my program opens the OBJ file specified and parses it using the parsing engine discussed in the tutorial here - http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-7-model-loading/#Reading_the_file.

The object I am trying to render is the Cube located on the same tutorial page URL.

I believe my problem lies in my display(void) function. After I execute          `glutDisplayFunc(display);` in my main(), I am presented with a black window, rather than my rendered model.

This is my current display(void) function:

```
void display(void)
{
    GLuint vbo;

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3) * 3, &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, vertices.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3) * 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, &vertices[0]);

    // check OpenGL error
    GLenum err;
    while ((err = glGetError()) != GL_NO_ERROR)
    {
        printf("OpenGL error: %u", err);
    }

    glEnd();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

And here is the data my parser reads in, perhaps it is a parsing issue:

`Success: GLEW_OK
Success: Opened OBJ File cube.obj
Read in Vertices: 1.000000,     -1.000000,      -1.000000
Read in Vertices: 1.000000,     -1.000000,      1.000000
Read in Vertices: -1.000000,    -1.000000,      1.000000
Read in Vertices: -1.000000,    -1.000000,      -1.000000
Read in Vertices: 1.000000,     1.000000,       -1.000000
Read in Vertices: 0.999999,     1.000000,       1.000001
Read in Vertices: -1.000000,    1.000000,       1.000000
Read in Vertices: -1.000000,    1.000000,       -1.000000
Read in texture coordinate: 0.748573,   0.750412
Read in texture coordinate: 0.749279,   0.501284
Read in texture coordinate: 0.999110,   0.501077
Read in texture coordinate: 0.999455,   0.750380
Read in texture coordinate: 0.250471,   0.500702
Read in texture coordinate: 0.249682,   0.749677
Read in texture coordinate: 0.001085,   0.750380
Read in texture coordinate: 0.001517,   0.499994
Read in texture coordinate: 0.499422,   0.500239
Read in texture coordinate: 0.500149,   0.750166
Read in texture coordinate: 0.748355,   0.998230
Read in texture coordinate: 0.500193,   0.998728
Read in texture coordinate: 0.498993,   0.250415
Read in texture coordinate: 0.748953,   0.250920
Read in Normals: 0.000000,      0.000000,       -1.000000
Read in Normals: -1.000000,     -0.000000,      -0.000000
Read in Normals: -0.000000,     -0.000000,      1.000000
Read in Normals: -0.000001,     0.000000,       1.000000
Read in Normals: 1.000000,      -0.000000,      0.000000
Read in Normals: 1.000000,      0.000000,       0.000001
Read in Normals: 0.000000,      1.000000,       -0.000000
Read in Normals: -0.000000,     -1.000000,      0.000000
Reached end of file
Out Vertices Size: 234`

glGetError() has not produced an error for me once, so I was not able to debug the issue that way.

Any suggestions / input?

Comment: The cube is build around the origin, so if the camera is not moved backward you might not see it because you only "see" the back faces of the cube and they are not rendered because you might have culling enabled (default). Did you try to move the camera around? As a second hint you might want to double check the winding order of the triangles. - Also usually you call glGenBuffers and glBufferData only once per object and not every frame to this during initialization...

Comment: Yes I have moved the camera around but only black screen results. As for your second hint, I did call glGenBuffers and glBufferData only once for this object, in display(void). Thanks for your reply

Comment: In addition to what @AndonM.Coleman said, your call to glDrawElements is most likely incorrect. You do not appear to have an index buffer (since vertices appears to be your position/normals etc). Instead you should do glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertices.size()).

Answer (score 2):

None of those commands (including `glGetError (...)`) are valid between `glBegin (...)` and `glEnd (...)`. If you move the calls to `glGetError` to come after `glEnd`, you should get `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` one or more times.

Remove `glBegin` and `glEnd`, they serve no purpose in this code, and only render the rest of your commands invalid.

> #### Name
>
> > [`glBegin`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glBegin.xml) — delimit the vertices of a primitive or a group of like primitives
>
> #### C Specification
>
> > void glBegin(    GLenum      mode);
>
> #### Description
>
> > [...]
> >
> > Only a subset of GL commands can be used between glBegin and glEnd. The commands are glVertex, glColor, glSecondaryColor, glIndex, glNormal, glFogCoord, glTexCoord, glMultiTexCoord, glVertexAttrib, glEvalCoord, glEvalPoint, glArrayElement, glMaterial, and glEdgeFlag. Also, it is acceptable to use glCallList or glCallLists to execute display lists that include only the preceding commands. ***If any other GL command is executed between glBegin and glEnd, the error flag is set and the command is ignored.***

---

Regarding the rest of your code, you should not be generating a new buffer every frame. Do that once during initialization, add a vertex pointer, and change your draw command to `glDrawArrays (...)`:

```
glDrawArrays (GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertices.size());
```

`glDrawElements (...)` is only to be used if you have an index buffer. Unless I completely misunderstood the structure of your data, `vertices` is your vertex data, and does not store a list of indices.

---

#### Update 1:

After reading the tutorial your question is based on, the following changes are necessary when you load your .obj model:

```
GLuint buffers [3];
glGenBuffers(3, buffers);

// Position Buffer = 0
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers [0]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3), &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexPointer (3, GL_FLOAT, 0, NULL);
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^ Sources data from VBO bound to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`, so a NULL pointer is OK
glEnableClientState (GL_VERTEX_ARRAY); // Use this array for drawing

// Tex Coords = 1
glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers [1]);
glBufferData (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uvs.size () * sizeof (glm::vec2), &uvs [0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glTexCoordPointer   (2, GL_FLOAT, 0, NULL);
glEnableClientState (GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

// Normals = 2
glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers [2]);
glBufferData (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normals.size () * sizeof (glm::vec3), &normals [0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glNormalPointer (GL_FLOAT, 0, NULL);
glEnableClientState (GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
```

Keep in mind, once you learn to use shaders, you should stop using functions such as `glVertexPointer (...)` and `glEnableClientState (...)`. You will be expected to use `glVertexAttribPointer (...)` and `glEnableVertexAttribArray (...)` instead.

I wrote the code this way so you can get something up and running immediately, but it's not the modern way of writing GL software.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your reply and consideration.

I understand why glBegin() and glEnd() were causing issues and I've removed them. I have also changed the draw command to glDrawArrays (GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertices.size());.

Also, I have removed glGenBuffers(), glBindBuffer(), and glBufferData() from display(void) and placed them in main, since I assume having them in display(void) was causing a new buffer to be generated every frame.

However, I am still seeing a black window displayed, even though everything compiles okay.

What exactly do you mean by "add a vertex pointer"?

Comment: @Coder: Probably better if I show you. I just took a peak at the tutorial this is based on, and I think I have enough information to add this to my answer in a couple of minutes.

Comment: @Coder: Are you familiar with shaders at this point? The original tutorial was written assuming you were going to use them, but I can write this answer using old-style vertex arrays (without shaders) if need be.

Comment: At this point I am not familiar with them. My next step will be to implement one, once I am able to get the model to just display normally. Thank you very much sir

Comment: @Coder: I'll take a look at it tomorrow morning.

Comment: And I will keep working hard on this and try to have a solution waiting for you in the morning. Thank you once again for everything so far, goodnight.

Comment: Andon, I deleted my earlier comment because I've updated the links below. Pastebin URL to the code I'm using to display the Triangle and Cube, including the display() function. - http://pastebin.com/9pPShmX2
I'm able to display the Triangle from tutorial2 using the "triangle_data" array of vectors - http://tinyurl.com/brdcnz9. However, I'm not able to display the Cube (http://tinyurl.com/monsngq), I get only a white box, even though I set the background color to be red. The triangle on the other hand renders a red background, and the triangle is drawn white. I feel like I am close. Thank you.

Comment: @Coder: Sorry for the delay - it sounds like your problem is simply a lack of color information in the vertex buffer for your .obj. Right now you have `position`, `normal` and `uv`. If you apply a texture to the object that will give it some color (and that is what `uv` is for), or if you apply lighting (which is what `normal` is for). However, in-lieu of either of those things and without a per-vertex color, a constant color will be assigned.

Comment: Nice to hear from you again! In addition to the triangle, I am now able to render a 2D square. My goal is to render a 3D cube. The 2D square is being rendered using data that SHOULD be rendering a 3D cube, which is the problem I'm having. I have set the background color of my window to bright red and my model renders in white so I know at least it's rendering something.

Do you know why it's rendering the cube in 2D instead of 3D? My main() and my display() functions are very simple, I have pastied them here: https://pastee.org/6pudj

Comment: Update: I now can see the 3D cube! I can make out the shape with my eyes, but it's clearly missing textures that would make it look much better and "real". Here's a screenshot of the "cube". I believe the cube is rendering correctly! Is my next step to add shaders so that it will look distinguished when rendered? Here's a screenshot of what I'm describing: http://i.imgur.com/xRl6bgF.png

Comment: @Coder: You don't need shaders for that, you can apply textures using the fixed-function (non-shader) pipeline. Your next step would be to learn how to load textures, to be honest.